# I don't know the dlopen() path on Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I need some help with dlopen() on Android NDK.

What path should I use in it? The full path to the library or just the library in my app?

Comment: There's very little information in your question. Once you've obtained the `ApplicationInfo` instance for your app you can read its [`nativeLibraryDir` field](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#nativeLibraryDir). How you go about obtaining that `ApplicationInfo` instance depends a bit on how your app is written, which we don't know.

Comment: I wanna use dlopen() to open a library from the external storage directory, I wanna know if that is possible.

Comment: Why not just try it? Call [`getExternalFilesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) and use that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the full path. In Android, the system runs an app without setting current directory, and it is not common practice for apps to set one.

It is possible to open a library from the external storage, but please note that Google [Play Store Developer Policy](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/) explicitly prohibits running code that does not come from Play Store.